# Python OS.WALK Remove Directories

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.walk

I'm trying to remove directories from os.walk (I don't need the files from those dirs)

My code:

```
def findit(root, exclude_files=[], exclude_dirs=[]):
    exclude_files = (fnmatch.translate(i) for i in exclude_files)
    exclude_files = '('+')|('.join(exclude_files)+')'
    exclude_files = re.compile(exclude_files)
    exclude_dirs = (os.path.normpath(i) for i in exclude_dirs)
    exclude_dirs = (os.path.normcase(i) for i in exclude_dirs)
    exclude_dirs = set(exclude_dirs)
    return (os.path.join(r,f)
           for r,_,f in os.walk(root)
           if os.path.normpath(os.path.normcase(r)) not in exclude_dirs
           for f in f
           if not exclude_files.match(os.path.normcase(f)))
```

It works filtering the files, when I try to filter out c:/windows it will still show my files from windows dirs am I missing something?

```
   filelist = list(findit('c:/',exclude_files = ['*.dll', '*.dat', '*.log', '*.exe'], exclude_dirs = ['c:/windows', 'c:/program files', 'c:/else']))
```

Comment: My apologies, missed that you were returning a generator expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When filtering out directories, you are *not* preventing `os.walk()` from going into subdirectories.

You'll need to clear the `dirs` list for this to happen:

```
def findit(root, exclude_files=[], exclude_dirs=[]):
    exclude_files = (fnmatch.translate(i) for i in exclude_files)
    exclude_files = '('+')|('.join(exclude_files)+')'
    exclude_files = re.compile(exclude_files)
    exclude_dirs = (os.path.normpath(i) for i in exclude_dirs)
    exclude_dirs = (os.path.normcase(i) for i in exclude_dirs)
    exclude_dirs = set(exclude_dirs)
    for current, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        if os.path.normpath(os.path.normcase(current)) in exclude_dirs:
            # exclude this dir and subdirectories
            dirs[:] = []
            continue
        for f in files:
            if not exclude_files.match(os.path.normcase(f)):
                yield os.path.join(current, f)
```

The `dirs[:] = []` assignment clears the list in place; it removes all dirnames from the list. As this list is shared with `os.walk()` and the latter uses this list to subsequently visit sub-directories, this effectively stops `os.walk()` from visiting those subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the reply above made me wonder.  Seemed to me the os.walk was missing and the root parameter did not seem to be used as needed.  Also, the case of either of the optional arguments being the empty list should work. Suggesting a slight variation with less namespace look-up and exclude wildcards for directories at each directory level:

```
import os
import re
import fnmatch
import os.path


def findit(root, exclude_files=[], exclude_dirs=[], exclude_dirs_wc=[]):
    """Generate all files found under root excluding some.

    Excluded files are given as a list of Unix shell-style wildcards
    that exclude matches in each directory.  Excluded directories are
    assumed to be paths starting at root; no wildcards.  Directory
    wildcards at each level can be supplied.

    """
    # Less namespace look-up.
    join = os.path.join
    normpath = os.path.normpath; normcase = os.path.normcase
    #
    def make_exclude_regex_from(lst):
        if len(lst):
            lst = (fnmatch.translate(i) for i in lst)
            lst = "({})".format(")|(".join(lst))
            lst = re.compile(lst)
        return lst
    #
    exclude_files = make_exclude_regex_from(exclude_files)
    exclude_dirs_wc = make_exclude_regex_from(exclude_dirs_wc)
    if len(exclude_dirs):
        exclude_dirs = (normpath(i) for i in exclude_dirs)
        exclude_dirs = (normcase(i) for i in exclude_dirs)
        exclude_dirs = set(exclude_dirs)
    for current, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        current_dir = normpath(normcase(current))
        if exclude_dirs and current_dir in exclude_dirs:
            # Prune set of dirs to exclude.
            exclude_dirs.discard(current_dir)
            # Disregard sub-directories.
            dirs[:] = []  # IN PLACE, since it is a loop var.
            continue
        if exclude_dirs_wc:
            for dd in dirs[:]:
                if exclude_dirs_wc.match(normcase(dd)):
                    dirs.remove(dd)  # IN PLACE
        if exclude_files:
            for ff in files[:]:
                if exclude_files.match(normcase(ff)):
                    files.remove(ff)  # IN PLACE; also a loop var.
        for f in files:
            yield join(current,f)
```

Comment: yes I did notice the os.walk was missing I have fixed it myself and it worked can you explain your code? I have also noticed you edited the exclude files function with re.compile can you explain it also how is the speed in this compared to the above answer

Comment: Not quite sure what you would like me to explain.  I'll try.  As for the exclude_files and format it does the same thing, but uses less temporaries under the hood.  The extra logic is in place to cater for the cases when either is the empty list; can probably be coded in a better way. Regarding speed I have  not measured.  A wild guess would be that having less namespace look-ups can be an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyword "continue" to skip the iteration while traversing using os.walk("pathName")

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(pathName):
    # Write regular expression or a string to skip the desired folder
    dirpath_pat = re.search(pattern, dirpath)
    if dirpath_pat:
        if dirpath_pat.group(0):
            continue
```